# ImageIO.read(URL input) не считывает картинку

Tags: java, изображения, url

В данный момент пишу утилиту, которая должна, помимо прочего, выгружать на жесткий диск картинки с сайта. Для работы с картинками использую **ImageIO.read(URL input)**, однако с некоторых URL метод отказывается читать картинку возвращая null. Пример:
`Image image = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/91/Wikiversity-logo.svg/28px-Wikiversity-logo.svg.png"));`
вернет null, хотя, если вбить ссылку в браузер все чудесно открывается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем url используется http, а надо ходить по https

```
ImageIO.read(new URL("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/91/Wikiversity-logo.svg/28px-Wikiversity-logo.svg.png"));
```